# Property file changes not seen in Websphere Liberty deployments

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, websphere-liberty

I have a Spring MVC app deployed on my local Liberty Server. Everything was fine until I've created a new workspace in Eclipse to work on a side branch.

My problem is; I can't seem to publish new property changes (which is used on spring:message tags in JSPs) to my Liberty Server. **Keep in mind that I can very well publish changes for Java, JSP, JS and HTML files, but it just won't see my newly added property key/value pairs. Previously added pairs are working fine**

My MessageSource bean configuration is like this;

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="com.myproject.components.ExposedResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>file://${PROJECT_HOME}/settings/webMessages/user_homepage_en</value>
                <value>file://${PROJECT_HOME}/settings/webMessages/register_messages_en</value>
                <value>file://${PROJECT_HOME}/settings/webMessages/template_messages_en</value>
                <value>file://${PROJECT_HOME}/settings/webMessages/login_messages_en</value>

           </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

A sample snippet from `login_messages_en.properties` (first 4 entries are working fine, last 2 entries are newly added an does not work):

```
login.wizard.step1             = Step 1
login.wizard.step2             = Step 2
login.wizard.step3             = Step 3
login.wizard.step4             = Step 4

login.userInformation          = User Information
login.registerPopup            = Register Now
```

When I try to use them in JSP code like this:

```
<label><spring:message code="login.userInformation" /></label>
```

I get the exception:

> Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under
>   code 'login.userInformation' for locale 'en'.

What I've tried so far:

- Maven Update / Clean Install the project
- Clean Server on Next Start option on Liberty Server
- Remove all WAR files, run the server empty, then add them back in
- Checked with my colleagues and verified same code works on their machines

Answer (score 1):

did u check your jvm.options properties? maybe your project definition properties point different path.